# Why is .CHILDREN slower than .MEMBERS?

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have two identical queries. One uses the `.CHILDREN` to retrieve members while other uses `.MEMBERS`. They are being applied to natural hierarchies. I am consistently finding that .MEMBERS returns results generally faster(sometimes much faster) than `.CHILDREN`. Below are the queries, messages and perfmon extracts from MDX studio which I found had the maximum variance.

**Query 1 (Using .MEMBERS)**

```
with set abc as
[Accident Cause].[Accident Cause Code].members

member measures.bcd as
sum(existing abc, [Measures].[Claim As Of - Count])

select {[Measures].[Claim As Of - Count], measures.bcd} on 0,
[Accident Cause].[Accident Cause Code].members on 1
from [aw cube]

--5 seconds
```

*Executing the query ...
Obtained object of type: Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.CellSet
Formatting.
Cell set consists of 1126 rows and 3 columns.
Done formatting.
Execution complete*

```
NON EMPTYs        : 0
Autoexists        : 0
EXISTINGs         : 1125
SE queries        : 0
Flat cache insert : 2
Cache hits        : 0
Cache misses      : 0
Cache inserts     : 0
Cache lookups     : 0
Memory Usage KB   : 4992
```

---

**Query 2 (Using .CHILDREN)**

```
with set abc as
[Accident Cause].[Accident Cause Code].children

member measures.bcd as
sum(existing abc, [Measures].[Claim As Of - Count])

select {[Measures].[Claim As Of - Count], measures.bcd} on 0,
[Accident Cause].[Accident Cause Code].children on 1
from [aw cube]
```

*Executing the query ...
Obtained object of type: Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.CellSet
Formatting.
Cell set consists of 1125 rows and 3 columns.
Done formatting.
Execution complete*

```
NON EMPTYs        : 0
Autoexists        : 0
EXISTINGs         : 1124
SE queries        : 0
Flat cache insert : 1124
Cache hits        : 0
Cache misses      : 0
Cache inserts     : 0
Cache lookups     : 0
Memory Usage KB   : 3744

--41 seconds
```

While I am aware of conceptual differences between these functions, I don't understand why there might be so much variations in performance.

**Edit - Results on Adventure Works**

```
with set abc as
[Geography].[City].members

member measures.bcd as
sum(existing abc,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])

select {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount], measures.bcd} on 0,
[Geography].[City].members on 1
from [Adventure Works]


/*
Time              : 503 ms
Calc covers       : 0
Cells calculated  : 2938
Sonar subcubes    : 1186
NON EMPTYs        : 0
Autoexists        : 0
EXISTINGs         : 588
SE queries        : 2
Flat cache insert : 1
Cache hits        : 1180
Cache misses      : 0
Cache inserts     : 0
Cache lookups     : 1180
Memory Usage KB   : 0
*/

with set abc as
[Geography].[City].children

member measures.bcd as
sum(existing abc,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])

select {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount], measures.bcd} on 0,
[Geography].[City].children on 1
from [Adventure Works]



/*
Time              : 843 ms
Calc covers       : 0
Cells calculated  : 1174
Sonar subcubes    : 589
NON EMPTYs        : 0
Autoexists        : 0
EXISTINGs         : 587
SE queries        : 588
Flat cache insert : 0
Cache hits        : 1176
Cache misses      : 0
Cache inserts     : 0
Cache lookups     : 1176
Memory Usage KB   : 28912        
*/
```

Comment: ...wish perfMon worked in my instance of `MDXStudio` ! (I've tried reinstalling). Sourav - Do you get the same difference if you run against `AdvWrks`?

Comment: I suppose Children needs to apply something like Descendants before returning results, the processor needs to exclude members that are not children ....so maybe a little more processing required. (but I do not know for sure)

Comment: Fair point. If that is the case, then probably `.CHILDREN` should be tried to be avoided.

Comment: @whytheq - on adventure works too, I could see that `.CHILDREN` took more time. Have edited the question with the results.

Comment: they do different things Sourav - maybe a better comparison would be DESCENDANTS vs CHILDREN

Comment: I agree they are two different things But still in lot of places, I feel `.CHILDREN` is a *neater* function.

Comment: but Children is doing the same sort of thing as Descendants - if you compare these two do you get the same performance?